# XML file in class library of net 5 hosted in MAUI can't be read

Tags: c#, maui

The file located in class library of dot net 5 and MAUI hosted it.

```
var configurationXml = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(@"Configuration.xml");
```

When I read this file from volume D is ok.

But when I put the file in class library or MAUI I got exception.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\Configuration.xml'.'

Comment: Are you using the correct location to locate the file?

Comment: Yes I tried to put the file in the Class library and hosted MAUI.

Comment: AFAIK you can't include files in class libraries

Comment: private async Task<string> GetConfiguration()
        {
            var locationOfTheDll = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var locationOfTheXml = locationOfTheDll.Replace("Shared.dll", "Configuration.xml");
            var configurationXml = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(locationOfTheXml);
            return configurationXml;

         }  That solution work

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Seems like Environment.CurrentDirectory gives "C:\Windows\system32" in MAUI RC2