# Read Demo Data from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, maui

I am trying to load into my Maui/Blazor app an XML file with Customers in it.

This data.xml is in a different project to where my UI-Components are (one of which, calls the DemoData to be display on client request). The problem I have is that I cant get the path of this file to load the document.

I have tried this way:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string assemblyPath = ass.Location;
string assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
string filePath = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "Data","demodata", "data.xml");
doc.Load(filePath);
```

But the assemblyPath return null.

Comment: "returns an error" - it would be really helpful to know what this mystery error is.  And why are you using `HttpClient` to read a local file?  Is this file part of your project?  Or a file located elsewhere in the file system?  What platform are you doing this on?

Comment: also, take the time to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows)

Comment: This is the error: "Unhandled exception rendering component: An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set."

Comment: Ok, let me check that Docs. I dont know why but i always end up checking the C# docs and never the Maui ones :P. Thx!! The file is in my system. The http way was just one way i have used before and wanted to give it a try, but should not be necesary

Comment: `HttpClient` is for creating http requests, not reading files from the local filesystem

Comment: "in my system" is not very descriptive.  And you have not explained what platform you are running this on.

Comment: in my system i mean in one of the 5 projects i have inside my solution. The Platform is Maui. I have seen that you have answered a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334145/xml-file-in-class-library-of-net-5-hosted-in-maui-cant-be-read I am trying to implement the same solution

Comment: MAUI is not a platform.  Windows/Android/IOS is a platform.  If you are just trying to read an embedded resource, that is really the same for any .NET app

Comment: Maui runs on all of them, and so will my app. I dont need to get access to platform folder, so i dont think the platform plays a role here. Just need to reach the xml file in my project

Comment: You were very vague about the source of the file, so I couldn't discount that this was a platform specific problem (iOS and Android are much stricter than Windows).

Comment: "Access files in different projects" wouldn't be meaningul on mobile platforms. Each project will become an `Assembly`. Read about [Resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-7.0). Search for info on reading resource from another assemply.